# Problem with Lesson 5 code on newer version

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I am trying to get signed token up and running on the Plutus playground from lesson 5 and I'm running into an issue with I believe is a depreciated variable of PubKeyHash does any body know the solution to this problem. Im using version v2022-01-13.

Comment: Please provide the plutus-app version being used. The last time I checked, a `PaymentPubKeyHash` type has been introduced.